# Как связать объекты фреймов

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, нейронные-сети, tensorflow

Подскажите, пожалуйста, имеется видеоизображение (фильм с несколькими сценами), я разбила это видео на несколько фреймов, с помощью алгоритма распознавания распознала объекты на всех фреймах этого видео, теперь мне нужно связать объект фрейма с этим же объектом следующего фрейма, как это сделать? Координаты распознанных объектов имеются.